# Selenium Webdriver : How to get All cookies in the Current page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Trying to get all cookies in the current page using Chrome driver with java .
Please help me to retrieve all cookies in the page once after close browser and trying to open new browser with old cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Using the WebDriver API available at:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html

Get all cookies for current page and parse to Collection of cookie Objects:

```
     driver.manage().getCookies();
    //TODO Parse results to Cookie Objects and Do what you want
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting cookies from all domains
In automated tests there might be instances where we have to validate cookies of a website.

Webdriver has simple and powerful API to retrieve cookies of current page domain. Here is the sample code to read cookies:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetAllPageCookies()
        {
            return _driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.ToDictionary(cookie => cookie.Name, cookie => cookie.Value);
        }
```

Comment: This works for cookies within your domain, but doesn't give you the cookies from third party domains. So no, it's not all cookies, despite the property name :(