# How to change the default cookie container size in Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to set default cookie content when using Selenium for testing a web app, I think the default container size for cookie is 20, which causes the cookie being truncated since some have more than 20 items in it. I googled and searched SO to no avail, anyone knows how to, or maybe give me pointer to avoid this trouble if this is not possible?

```
var options = new ChromeOptions{}; 
_driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the security of most web browser is such that you can get only the name and value from the cookie, just so you know.  Not too sure about c# but

```
 driver.manage().getCookies())
```

returns an array of the cookies in Java; but [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912204/selenium-webdriver-how-to-get-all-cookies-in-the-current-page) gives the syntax in C#

```
return _driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.ToDictionary(cookie => cookie.Name, cookie => cookie.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still need to know if there is a way to change the default cookie container per domain size from 20 to something bigger on chromedriver, since one of the cookie I need to copy has more than 20 object in it.

Comment: There is no such limit imposed by chromedriver. I have tests that pull hundreds of cookies and never changed anything in any configuration. The problem must be something else.

Comment: oh I see, thank you for telling me that, I'll look for other things that may cause the error then.