# Selenium: driver.get_cookies() returns incomplete list of cookies

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cookies

The cookies returned are as follows:

```
[
    {
        "domain": "www.carid.com",
        "name": "uxatc",
        "value": "%13%18%07%13%0D%07%13J%07%14J%07%0DJ%07%13%14%07%13I%07%12%13%0F%09%0E%1E%07%13%1F%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%14%0F%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%08%17%0F%09%0E%1E%07%16%16%07%16%1F%07%0F%08%07%0F%16%07%10%1F%07%15%16%07%0D%08%0D%12%08%12%19%17%1E%07%0C%10%07%1F%1F%07%1F%10%07%0C%1F%07%15%0C%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%1F%19%07%03%02%07%08%18%07%0FJJNMMINOJLJCLK%07%0FI%07",
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": false
    },
    {
        "domain": ".carid.com",
        "name": "xid",
        "value": "21f70e8bba820dcaf620307b1717f90c",
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": true,
        "secure": false
    },
    {
        "domain": ".carid.com",
        "name": "xidRes",
        "value": "21f70e8bba820dcaf620307b1717f90c",
        "expiry": 1567463776,
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": true,
        "secure": false
    },
    {
        "domain": "www.carid.com",
        "name": "store_language",
        "value": "US",
        "expiry": 1597790176,
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": true
    },
    {
        "domain": "www.carid.com",
        "name": "uxat",
        "value": "%13%18K%07%0DJ%07%13J%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%14J%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%13%1F%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%14%0F%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%08%17%0F%09%0E%1E%07%16%16%07%16%1F%07%0F%08%07%0F%16%07%10%1F%07%15%16%07%0D%08%0D%12%08%12%19%17%1E%07%0C%10%07%1F%1F%07%1F%10%07%0C%1F%07%15%0C%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%1F%19%07%13IK%07",
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": false
    },
    {
        "domain": "www.carid.com",
        "name": "uxid2",
        "value": "16fc88Ve3eb83cfbccGc5",
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": false
    },
    {
        "domain": "www.carid.com",
        "name": "uxid",
        "value": "8a58hVe3eb83cfc13Ym8",
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": false
    }
]
```

There are 7 cookies, but the browser has 17 cookies:

[image: firefox cookies]

Why are there missing cookies? Is there a way to get all the cookies?

Comment: I think that selenium can get only the cookies of the current domain.

Comment: They are third party analytics cookies to trace users activity. Either the automated setup blocks them or the page detects the automation and skips them.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, because you didn't wait for the page to fully load before getting the cookies. I checked the site and observe the cookies status. Before the page fully loads on car selecting divs, there are less cookies than after the page is fully loaded.

Even if the driver thinks that the page is fully loaded, maybe it's not. It might run some background scripts. It's best to check for it before you want to do anything.

Working example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
# opt.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get("https://carid.com")
cookies_before = driver.get_cookies()
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "select-vehicle-button")]')
        ))
print("Loaded!")
cookies_after = driver.get_cookies()
print(bool(cookies_before == cookies_after))
print(f"Cookies before: {len(cookies_before)}.")
print(f"Cookies after: {len(cookies_after)}.")
print(cookies_after)
driver.quit()
```

Output when before & after are different (only sometimes):

```
Loaded!
False
Cookies before: 5.
Cookies after: 17.
```

---

Notes: careful if you're running this in headless. Chrome headless will not work on this site, Firefox headless will.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably use requests module to get all the cookies you want to see.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
      s.get('website.com')
      print(s.cookies)
```

if it doesn't, try

```
print(s.cookies._cookies)
```

Comment: What if you need to render javascript?

Comment: try driver.manage().getCookies();
more in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912204/selenium-webdriver-how-to-get-all-cookies-in-the-current-page/24920215

Answer (score 0):

### get_cookies()

[`get_cookies()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookies) method returns a set of dictionaries, corresponding to cookies visible in the current session.

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

---

### This usecase

As the [*AUT* (application under test)](https://www.carid.com/) is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) based, while storing the [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) you need to you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for some of the *JavaScript* enabled element to turn `element_to_be_clickable()` and then collect the cookies.

Further, [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532784/error-when-loading-cookies-into-a-python-request-session/59843387#59843387) contains a lot more information including *domain*, *name*, *value*, *httpOnly*, *secure* etc. Hence a single key/value pair may not suffice. However, you can construct your own dictionary with the *name* and its corresponding *value* of the cookies.

---

### Demonstration

As an example:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://carid.com")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.select-vehicle-button")))
  cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
  print("*****")
  print(f"Cookies list: {len(cookies_list)}")
  print("*****")
  cookies_dict = {}
  for cookie in cookies_list:
      cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
  print(cookies_dict)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  *****
  Cookies list: 16
  *****
  {'xid': '7c85b0b99fb3dcf885d655c31a8fda40', 'store_language': 'US', 'uxat': '%13%18K%07%0DJ%07%13J%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%14J%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%13%1F%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%14%0F%1D%1A%17%08%1E%07%08%17%0F%09%0E%1E%07%16%16%07%16%1F%07%0F%08%07%0F%16%07%10%1F%07%15%16%07%0D%08%0D%12%08%12%19%17%1E%07%0C%10%07%1F%1F%07%1F%10%07%0C%1F%07%15%0C%0F%09%0E%1E%07%1F%19%07%13IK%07', 'uxid2': 'k8e2gUea05cdacf54K17d', 'uxid': '1ecehjYea05cdad009Q12n', '_gaexp': 'GAX1.2.pKl-9WqUR9OGPHEwCLKksQ.18690.1', '_ga': 'GA1.2.2081848464.1608191540', '_gid': 'GA1.2.1590349607.1608191540', '_gat': '1', '_uetsid': 'cb51ab90403c11eba41c7dda4c599643', '_uetvid': 'cb524450403c11eb89d6b3285069b4af', '__gads': 'ID=80ccbeefc3c87d2b-22e1ddad3cc5008a:T=1608191860:RT=1608191860:S=ALNI_MYhnP8XRpcV3S7HM2qf0XPr8SRRaQ', 'RefererCookie': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carid.com%2F', '_fbp': 'fb.1.1608191549984.531722481', 'xidRes': '7c85b0b99fb3dcf885d655c31a8fda40', 'uxid3': '83g8jSea05ce07dddQ117'}
  ```

---

### Observation

This count of **16** cookies exactly matches with the count of cookies observed within the *Firefox* browser.

- Browser Snapshot:

[image: carid]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still encountering this issue despite waiting for the page to load properly.

`driver.get_cookies()` can only get cookies from the domain currently loaded in the browsers URL-bar (and it's subdomains).

In my case I managed to get past this issue by temporarily directing my browsers to the domain belonging to the specific cookie I wanted to use.

`driver.get("https://url.of.the.cookie")`

`driver.get_cookies()`

This allowed me to get and examine those remaining, previously unlisted, cookies.

Special thanks to Titus Fortner over at Selenium for asking [the relevant question](https://seleniumhq.slack.com/archives/C5PJXA814/p1691421799049089).