# Error when loading cookies into a Python request session

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to load cookies into my request session in Python from selenium exported cookies, however when I do it returns the following error:
"'list' object has no attribute 'extract_cookies'"

```
def load_cookies(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

initial_state= requests.Session()
initial_state.cookies=load_cookies(time_cookie_file)
search_requests = initial_state.get(search_url)
```

Everywhere I see this should work, however my cookies are a list of dictionaries, which is what I understand all cookies are, and why I assume this works with Selenium. However for some reason it does not work with requests, any and all help in this regard would be really great, it feels like I am missing something obvious!

Cookies have been dumped from Selenium using:

```
with open("Filepath.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), f)
```

An example of the cookies would be (slightly obfuscated):

```
[{'domain': '.website.com',
  'expiry': 1640787949,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': '_ga',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'GA1.2.1111111111.1111111111'},
 {'domain': 'website.com',
  'expiry': 1585488346,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': '__pnahc',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': '0'}]
```

I have now managed to load in the cookies as per the answer below, however it does not seem like the cookies are loaded in properly as they do not remember anything, however if I load the cookies in when browsing through Selenium they work fine.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? because intial_state.cookies gives me `AttributeError`

Comment: No, just a straight error with "list' object ...", the cookies have been dumped from Selenium using with open("Filepath.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), f)

Comment: Can you put an example of how loaded `driver.get_cookies()` look like?

Comment: Use json to store cookie. It should work.

Answer (score 6):

### Cookie

The **`Cookie`** HTTP request header contains stored `HTTP cookie` previously sent by the server with the `Set-Cookie` header. A [HTTP cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) is a small piece of data that a server sends to the user's web browser. The browser may store the **cookies** and send it back with the next request to the same server. Typically, [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) to tell if two requests came from the same browser, keeping the user logged in.

---

### Demonstration using Selenium

To demonstrate the usage of cookies using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) we have stored the cookies using [pickle](/questions/tagged/pickle) once the user had logged into the website http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php. In the next step, we opened the same website, adding the cookies and was able to land as a logged in user.

- Code Block to store the cookies:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import pickle

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php')
  driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("abc123")
  driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123xyz")
  driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
  pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
  ```
- Code Block to use the stored cookies for automatic authentication:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import pickle

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php')
  cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
  for cookie in cookies:
      driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_cookie.php')
  ```

---

### Demonstration using Requests

To demonstrate usage of cookies using [session](/questions/tagged/session) and [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) we have accessed the site https://www.google.com, added a new dictionary of cookies:

```
{'name':'my_own_cookie','value': 'debanjan' ,'domain':'.stackoverflow.com'}
```

Next, we have used the same *requests* session to send another request which was successful as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import requests

  s1 = requests.session()
  s1.get('https://www.google.com')
  print("Original Cookies")
  print(s1.cookies)
  print("==========")
  cookie = {'name':'my_own_cookie','value': 'debanjan' ,'domain':'.stackoverflow.com'}
  s1.cookies.update(cookie)
  print("After new Cookie added")
  print(s1.cookies)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Original Cookies
  <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie 1P_JAR=2020-01-21-14 for .google.com/>, <Cookie NID=196=NvZMMRzKeV6VI1xEqjgbzJ4r_3WCeWWjitKhllxwXUwQcXZHIMRNz_BPo6ujQduYCJMOJgChTQmXSs6yKX7lxcfusbrBMVBN_qLxLIEah5iSBlkdBxotbwfaFHMd-z5E540x02-YZtCm-rAIx-MRCJeFGK2E_EKdZaxTw-StRYg for .google.com/>]>
  ==========
  After new Cookie added
  <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie domain=.stackoverflow.com for />, <Cookie name=my_own_cookie for />, <Cookie value=debanjan for />, <Cookie 1P_JAR=2020-01-21-14 for .google.com/>, <Cookie NID=196=NvZMMRzKeV6VI1xEqjgbzJ4r_3WCeWWjitKhllxwXUwQcXZHIMRNz_BPo6ujQduYCJMOJgChTQmXSs6yKX7lxcfusbrBMVBN_qLxLIEah5iSBlkdBxotbwfaFHMd-z5E540x02-YZtCm-rAIx-MRCJeFGK2E_EKdZaxTw-StRYg for .google.com/>]>
  ```

---

### Conclusion

Clearly, the newly added dictionary of cookies `{'name':'my_own_cookie','value': 'debanjan' ,'domain':'.stackoverflow.com'}` is pretty much in use within the second request.

---

### Passing Selenium Cookies to Python Requests

Now, if your usecase is to passing Selenium Cookies to Python Requests, you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle
import requests

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php')
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("abc123")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123xyz")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

# Storing cookies through Selenium
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
driver.quit()

# Passing cookies to Session
session = requests.session()  # or an existing session
with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
search_requests = session.get('https://www.google.com/')
print(session.cookies)
```

Comment: Interestingly it seems like the last part of your answer cannot easily be reversed if different domains are involved. Moving cookies from a selenium session into a webdriver session is not possible if the cookies are set for different domains as shown in some of the linked answers and the upstream bug report: https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1238

Comment: `session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))` gives `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` exception

Comment: to add to my last comment, answer by `@Jortega`, will solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Since you are replacing session.cookies (`RequestsCookieJar`) with a `list` which don't have those attributes, it won't work.

You can import those cookies one by one by using:

```
for c in your_cookies_list:
   initial_state.cookies.set(name=c['name'], value=c['value'])
```

I've tried loading the whole cookie but it seems like requests doesn't recognize those ones and returns:

```
TypeError: create_cookie() got unexpected keyword arguments: ['expiry', 'httpOnly']
```

requests accepts `expires` instead and `HttpOnly` comes nested within `rest`

**Update:**

We can also change the dict keys for `expiry` and `httpOnly` so that requests correctly load them instead of throwing an exception, by using `dict.pop()` which deletes an item from dict by the `key` and returns the `value` of deleted `key` so after we add a new `key` with deleted item `value` then unpack & pass them as `kwargs`:

```
for c in your_cookies_list:
    c['expires'] = c.pop('expiry')
    c['rest'] = {'HttpOnly': c.pop('httpOnly')}
    initial_state.cookies.set(**c)
```

Comment: But will the cookies not be missing domain and all the other metrics?

Comment: I tried mashable (random website with cookies to consent to as I am outside the US), however I load in the cookies but it does not register me clicking I consent during my selenium instance, any idea at all whats going wrong?

Comment: @nonein I don't understand exactly what are you trying to reach, can you elaborate with a reproducible example?

Comment: Apologies for being un clear. Essentially I want to access websites that require cookies, e.g. consent forms, logins etc., e.g. go on my stackoverflow account and send me an email whenever I get a post notification. My thought was to create the cookies using Selenium (press yes to consent form, login to stackoverflow etc.) and then reload the cookies in request whenever I was pulling a page. Please let me know if this makes sense otherwise I will amend my answer with a longer explanation

Comment: @nonein I think you can do that by just using `requests.Session` without needing to use selenium at all.

Comment: How would I for example consent to a form or log in?

Comment: @nonein check out HTTP *methods* such as `GET`, `POST` which are commonly used for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can get cookies and use only name/value. You'll need headers also. You can get them from dev tools or by using proxy.

Basic example:

```
driver.get('https://website.com/')

# ... login or do anything

cookies = {}
for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    cookies[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
# Write to a file if need or do something
# import json
# with open("cookies.txt", 'w') as f:
#    f.write(json.dumps(cookies))
```

And usage:

```
# Read cookies from file as Dict
# with open('cookies.txt') as reader:
#     cookies = json.loads(reader.read())

# use cookies
response = requests.get('https://website.com/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Stackoverflow headers example, some headers can be required some not. You can find information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header) and [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python). You can get request headers using dev tools Network tab:

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'stackoverflow.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'dnt': '1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'referer': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=Newest&tagMode=Watched&uqlId=8338',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
}
```

Comment: I have never seen anyone else mention that I also need headers as well as cookies, can you give me an example of what they look like?

Comment: You can find info about request headers in the answer update

Answer (score 0):

You can create a session. The session class handles cookies between requests.

```
s = requests.Session()


login_resp = s.post('https://example.com/login', login_data)
self.cookies = self.login_resp.cookies



cookiedictreceived = {}
cookiedictreceived=requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.login_resp.cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

So requests wants all "values" in your cookie to be a string.  Possibly the same with the "key". Cookies also does not want a list as your function `load_cookies` returns. Cookies can be created for the request.utils with `cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(...`.

Lets say I go to "https://stackoverflow.com/" with selenium and save the cookies as you have done.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle
import requests

#Go to the website
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Path\\To\\Your\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

#Save the cookies in a file
with open("C:\Path\To\Your\Filepath.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), f)

driver.quit()
#you function to get the cookies from the file.
def load_cookies(filename):
  with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    return pickle.load(f)

saved_cookies_list = load_cookies("C:\Path\To\Your\Filepath.pkl")

#Set request session
initial_state = requests.Session()
#Function to fix cookie values and add cookies to request_session
def fix_cookies_and_load_to_requests(cookie_list, request_session):
    for index in range(len(cookie_list)):
        for item in cookie_list[index]:
            if type(cookie_list[index][item]) != str:
                print("Fix cookie value: ", cookie_list[index][item])
                cookie_list[index][item] = str(cookie_list[index][item])
        cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(cookie_list[index])
        request_session.cookies.update(cookies)
    return request_session

initial_state_with_cookies = fix_cookies_and_load_to_requests(cookie_list=saved_cookies_list, request_session=initial_state)

search_requests = initial_state_with_cookies.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
print("search_requests:", search_requests)
```

Comment: @no nein  if you need help with keys not being strings we can handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Requests also accept `http.cookiejar.CookieJar` objects:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects